# Best way to represent a Matrix (2D-Array) of variable length in Java?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, arraylist, hashmap

I want to create a matrix with a variable number of rows which is filled during runtime. The number of rows depends on the data and is not known before the program starts. What I tried is this:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>> eMatrix = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
    HashMap<Integer, Double> row = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    while (i < foo.size() - 1) {
        if (foo.get(i) == 0) {
            row.put(0, foo.get(i));
        }
        if (foo.get(i) == 1) {
            ro.put(1, foo.get(i));
        }
        if (foo.get(i) == 2) {
            ro.put(2, foo.get(i));
        }
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            eMatrix.add(row);
        }
        row.clear();
        i++;
    }
```

The idea was that as ArrayLists and HashMaps can have variable size to create rows with the HashMap, and add these rows to the ArrayList resulting in a matrix. Now the problem is that `row.clear` clears the entries in `eMatrix` as well. Do you have a better idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific implementation problem can be solved by creating a new `HashMap` instance for each row of the matrix :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>> eMatrix = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>>();
while (i < foo.size() - 1) {
    HashMap<Integer, Double> row = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    if (foo.get(i) == 0) {
        row.put(0, foo.get(i));
    }
    if (foo.get(i) == 1) {
        ro.put(1, foo.get(i));
    }
    if (foo.get(i) == 2) {
        ro.put(2, foo.get(i));
    }
    if (!row.isEmpty()) {
        eMatrix.add(row);
    }
    i++;
}
```

That said, I would still try to use a simple 2D array (`double[][]`). You can initialize it at run time, once you know the required dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: Or `ArrayList<Double[]>` resp. ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`.

Comment: @neza Performance and better readability. When I see `new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Double>>()`, it's less trivial to realize this is a matrix representation compared to `new double[numRows][numCols]`. Beside that, `HashMap` is not ordered, so if you want to iterate over the columns of some row in order, you'll need some other Map implementation.